# Limit at infinity of continuous function and diverging sequences

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let two sequences ${x_n}$, ${y_n}$ of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $||x_n||\to\infty$, $||y_n||\to\infty$ and $||x_n-y_n||\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x_n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Does $f(y_n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: The answer is yes if $f$ is Lipschitz: $$\|f(y_n)\| \geq \|f(x_n)\| - \|f(x_n)-f(y_n)\|\geq \|f(x_n)\| - \text{Lip}(f)\|x_n-y_n\|\to \infty.$$ This seems to have to do with uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: How about if $f$ is not Lipschitz? I agree in that it seems to have to do with uniform continuity, but my though was that since the requirement that $f(y_n)\to\infty$ is quite strong, maybe we don't actually need uniform continuity.

Comment: Hint: consider $f(x) = x\sin(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Consider a continuous $g:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ such that $g(n)=n$ and $g(n+2^{-n})=0$ whenever $n\in\Bbb Z^+.$ Let $f(x)=g(\|x\|).$ Let $\|x_n\|=n$ and let $y_n=x_n(1+2^{-n}).$